# display value of database

Tags: c#, sql

i have code like this

```
Global.dbCon.Open();
int idQuestion;
kalimatSql = kalimatSql;
Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatSql);
if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
   while (Global.reader.Read()) {
       idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));
       //messageBox.Show(idQuestion.ToString()); -->first message box
   }
}
//messageBox.Show(idQuestion.ToString()); -->second message box
Global.dbCon.Close();
```

i don't have problem to display first messagebox, but how to display second messagebox

---

**edited**

i try to make code from @rhughes become a function (class) like this following code

```
Global.dbCon.Open();
List<int> idQuestions = new List<int>();
Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatSql);
if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
  while (Global.reader.Read()) {
     int idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));
     idQuestions.Add(idQuestion);
  }
}
Global.dbCon.Close();
foreach (int id in idQuestions) {
  return id;
}
```

but it's no work because not all code paths return a value...i wonder how corret way to do it?

Comment: and what is the **problem** ?

Comment: @Selman22 display second messageBox

Comment: you could say what do you want to display in the second messagebox!

Comment: @Selman22 He did - //messageBox.Show(idQuestion.ToString()); -->second message box

Comment: @rhughes it is unclear what he wants.does he want to display last idQuestion,or all idQuestions with a loop , or all idQuestions in the same time with one messagebox

Comment: @Selman22 u got a point....i want to display all id questions in different messagebox...sory if my question unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Global.dbCon.Open();

List<int> idQuestions = new List<int>();

kalimatSql = kalimatSql;

Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatSql);

if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
   while (Global.reader.Read()) {
       int idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));

       idQuestions.Add(idQuestion);
   }
}

Global.dbCon.Close();

foreach (int id in idQuestions)
{
    messageBox.Show(id.ToString());
}
```

What we are doing here is adding all of the question ids into a list and then displaying each of them afterwards.

Comment: i try to modif u code to become a function...but it's give error result, can u give me example how to proper way to do it?

Comment: @katik Sure. If you create a new question, we can fix it there.

Comment: i already create newquestion about it....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544189/function-return-value-not-all-code-paths-return