# function return value, not all code paths return

Tags: c#, function

hi I have code like this

```
Global.dbCon.Open();
List<int> idQuestions = new List<int>();
kalimatSql = kalimatSql;
Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatSql);
if (Global.reader.HasRows)
    while (Global.reader.Read())
    {
        int idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0)); 
        idQuestions.Add(idQuestion);
    }
Global.dbCon.Close();
foreach (int id in idQuestions)
    messageBox.Show(id.ToString());
```

I try to make edit it to function (class) so I can call it many times like this

```
private int sqlReader(string kalimatSql)
{
    int sqlReader(string kalimatSql){
    Global.dbCon.Open();
    List<int> idQuestions = new List<int>();
    Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatSql);
    if (Global.reader.HasRows)
        while (Global.reader.Read())
        {
            int idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));
            idQuestions.Add(idQuestion);
        }
    Global.dbCon.Close();
    foreach (int id in idQuestions)
        return id;
}
```

but it's not working because not all code paths return a value... I wonder what's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error occurred because, what will happened (or returned) when your last 'foreach' loop runs zero time?, in other sense what value should your code return when your 'idQuestions' has zero length?

in order to get rid of this, you change this code as

```
if(idQuestions.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (int id in idQuestions) {
       return id;
    }
}
else
    return -1;
```

Comment: this will give error if function is returning int value. how can u return null

Comment: it is just to explain you. you can return your own value either -1 or anything else to determine that function not returning an id.

Comment: Are you sure this is doing what you want? This solution will only return the first element of the list if it's not empty, is that the intended behavior?

Comment: @EricGagnon yeah i just need to return first statement..u're right maybe in another case this solution not run well, but in my project now it's run smooth

Comment: @katik Okay well if you only need the first element, I would suggest a simpler syntax: `return (idQuestions.Count > 0) ? idQuestions[0] : -1;`

Comment: @EricGagnon that's working like charm too can u tell me what is it name or maybe url for it, i wanna learn create simple code like that

Comment: @EricGagnon if u have time, please be kind to help my another question...it's still not have answer....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542101/delete-data-using-2-dialogform....

Comment: @katik No problem. Documentation for the ternary operator can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with this last part of your code:

```
    foreach (int id in idQuestions) {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The primary issue here is that you're not returning anything if `idQuestions` is empty (which is why you're receiving this error). But even if it's not empty, your code is returning the first time you enter the `foreach`'s body, thus returning only the first element from the list of *ids*.

I'm assuming you want to return the entire list of *ids*, which is convenient because you already have them all inside of a `List<>`. Simply change your code to this:

```
    return idQuestions;
}
```

The complete method should look like this (note the method signature):

```
private List<int> sqlReader(string kalimatSql) {
    Global.dbCon.Open();
    List<int> idQuestions = new List<int>();
    Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatSql);
    if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
        while (Global.reader.Read()) {
            int idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));
            idQuestions.Add(idQuestion);
        }
    }
    Global.dbCon.Close();

    //return the ids
    return idQuestions;
}
```

Comment: is that possible return idQuestion because idQuestion are list int <int> type not normal 'int'..i try this and get result error

Comment: Yep, you'd have to change the method signature (as shown in my answer). I assumed you would want to return all the ids your query returned because in your original method you are showing a messageBox for all the different values. If you modify your code to only return the first element, it can no longer reproduce that behavior. Simply provide more information next time so people can give you an accurate answer to your question.

Comment: yeah, it's my mistake not make my question clear....anyway if u have time, please be kind to help my another question...it's still not have answer even an answer so i can't get idea how to do it....stackoverflow.com/questions/21542101/

Answer (score 1):

What if there isnt any elements in `idQuestions`. foreach will never get executed.

I am supposing you are returning single integer value from ur function

so after foreach return default int. You got ur algorithm alltogether wrong. Only first Id will be returned if u implement second code version

```
Global.dbCon.Open();
List<int> idQuestions = new List<int>();
int deft=0;
Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatSql);
if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
  while (Global.reader.Read()) {
     int idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));
     idQuestions.Add(idQuestion);
  }
}
Global.dbCon.Close();
foreach (int id in idQuestions) {
  return id;
}

return deft;
```

Comment: Wrong, this will only return the first element.

Comment: Yes ofcourse that what I have written in my answer. We dont know what his function is returning

Comment: i can't use return default property it's give Error 'Syntax error, '(' expected' but when i try to change it to anyvalue it's run smooth

Comment: that isnt problem with default value but its syntax error i think. Actually default is keyword in c# so cant use it. FIXED

Comment: this run too...thanks for the answer it's really simple...anyway if u have time, please be kind to help my another question...it's still not have answer even an answer so i can't get idea how to do it....stackoverflow.com/questions/21542101/

Answer (score 1):

The last line:

```
foreach (int id in idQuestions) {
    return id;
}
```

Is the same as saying `if (idQuestions.Count > 0) { return idQuestions[0]; }`.

The error is because you are not returning a value at the end of your code flow. There are many ways to fix this in your case, but you need to figure out what a 'default' value would be (like `null` or `-1`.

You could do something like the following:

```
return (idQuestions.Count > 0 ? idQuestions[0] : -1)`
```

if a `-1` is a valid return value, or if your intent was to return the whole array (or null if invalid) you could something like this:

```
return (idQuestions.Count > 0 ? idQuestions : null)
```

hope that can help

Answer (score 1):

It seems very wrong to put return inside a foreach loop.

if you have multiple result ,you can return IEnumerable

```
foreach(int id in idQuestions)
   yield return id;
```

Comment: can't working...it's give error 'The body of 'iTVote.Quiz.sqlReader(string)' cannot be an iterator block because 'int' is not an iterator interface type

Comment: You need to change your method's signature. I assume it currently is `int sqlReader(string)` but it needs to be `IEnumerable<int> sqlReader(string)` for Johnny's solution to work. This is a cute solution but it is much slower and complicated than simply returning `idQuestion` directly.

Comment: @EricGagnon is this section u mean need changed to use this solution 'private int sqlReader( string kalimatSql)' to 'private IEnumerable<int> sqlReader(string kalimatSql)'

Comment: @katik I guess so. I omitted `private` as it has no impact on this conversation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your code that you are trying to fetch some ids from your data store. In that case, according to your code, it will return only id of first element returned from your data store. If I have understood your question properly, the code should be like this,

```
Global.dbCon.Open();
List<int> idQuestions = new List<int>();
Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatSql);
if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
  while (Global.reader.Read()) {
     int idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));
     idQuestions.Add(idQuestion);
  }
}
Global.dbCon.Close();

return idQuestions;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue there is that your one and only *return* statement is inside a *foreach* loop and the contents of that loop will never be executed if the list you enumerate is empty.  Why do you have a loop at all if you're going to return the first value in the list anyway though?

Comment: first i try to avoid using foreach too....see in my another question maybe u have better solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542796/display-value-of-database

Comment: Even in that question, you haven't actually explained what you're trying to achieve.  Displaying a message box is a means to an end, not an end in itself.  If you want to display multiple messages then a loop is the way to do it but there's no messages in your latest code.  What do you actually want this function to return?